# Laravel 4 writing an api ->save() returns NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-4, api-design

I am writing a very basic (at the moment) restful api, I am running a method that looks like this,

```
public function store()
{
    $user_details = Input::all();

    $user = new User;

    $user->firstname = $user_details['firstname'];
    $user->surname = $user_details['surname'];
    $user->email = $user_details['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($user_details['password']);
    $user->token = '';

    $user->save();

    return Response::json($user);
}
```

This returns NotFoundHttpException, however if I do `dd($user_details)` anywhere before the return I get the dump of the array, not the exceptions what is the problem?

Comment: please dump your array here ...

Comment: looks to failing when I get here `$user = new User;` I think it might be also a root problem,

`Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){

 Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');
 Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@get');
 Route::post('users/create', 'UsersController@store');

});`

Comment: You should really post those new pieces of code in an edit on your original post